# Match a string which contains array items with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

**Example:**

I have this string

```
"  [mc_gross] => 50.00  [invoice] => done  [address_details] => xyz  [protection_eligibility] => Eligible"
```

So, I have used the following code.

```
preg_match_all("/^\s{2}\[(.+?)\] \=\> /m", $in, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Preg_match_all returns the empty array but I want to return something like the below array with the offset values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>   [mc_gross] =>
                    [1] => 0
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => mc_gross
                    [1] => 3
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
          (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>   [invoice] =>
                    [1] => 21
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => invoice
                    [1] => 24
                )
        )

)
```

So that i could test the following code:

```
foreach($matches as $match) {
     $key = $match[1][0]; // matched string
     $offset = $match[0][1]; // starting point of the matched string
     // start returns starting point of matched string + string length of matched string
     $start = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: I would like to help you with this but what is the overall goal of your process?  Are you trying to validate the string based on the length of the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only used one of your flags, modified the regex pattern, and unset the full match (matches[0]) from the array then reset the keys.

This provides an array similar to your request but with clean key values:

```
$in="  [mc_gross] => 50.00  [invoice] => done  [address_details] => xyz  [protection_eligibility] => Eligible  ";
if(preg_match_all("/\[([^]]*?)\]\s=>\s(.*?)\s{2}/", $in, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
    unset($matches[0]);
    $matches=array_values($matches);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_export($matches);
    echo "</pre>";
}else{
    echo "no match";
}
```

The regex pattern [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1xeLcE/2) with explanation

Here is the var_export'ed array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'mc_gross',
      1 => 5,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'invoice',
      1 => 26,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 'address_details',
      1 => 45,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 'protection_eligibility',
      1 => 71,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => '50.00',
      1 => 18,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'done',
      1 => 38,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 'xyz',
      1 => 65,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 'Eligible',
      1 => 98,
    ),
  ),
)
```